# express.js CSURF cookie and header match, returning 403

Tags: node.js, express, csrf

I have a simple express server setup like:

```
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(csurf({ cookie: true }));
  // routes
  app.use(Routes imported from another file);
```

The client is currently just a simple form in react. I am loading some initial data before the react app loads and the csrf cookie is being set there.

I have a simple function for parsing the csrf cookie client side. I'm proxying the express server in create-react-app so I can't just set a meta tag in the header.

```
const csrfToken = () => {
  const cookies = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split(';');
  const token = cookies.find(cookie => cookie.includes('_csrf'));

  if (token) {
    return token.split('=')[1]
  }
}
```

I am using fetch to send along data and the token

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken()
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ ...body })
    });
```

I've tried commenting out the line that tells the app to use csurf and checking that everything is present on the request. I can verify that the cookie and the header are matching in every request I send. Everything seems correct, but I am still getting a 403 error so I must be missing something. I'm at a lost to what it could be and all I could find googling is other people setting up their apps very similarly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reading the content of the `_csrf` cookie and sending it back inside `X-CSRF-Token` header. This will not work.

The `csurf` middleware running inside Express has been configured by this code: `app.use(csurf({ cookie: true }));` to generate the `_csrf` cookie and send it to the client. The middleware expects you to:

1. Generate the second piece of CSRF data on the server.
2. Attach the second piece of data to the response sent to a client. As a result, the response arrives to the client with both the `_csrf` cookie and the second piece of data attached.
3. Ensure the incoming request from the client has the same `_csrf` cookie and the second piece of data copied into one of the six predefined places/locations (such as 'X-CSRF-Token' header or another location).

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59549909/12005425) answer for more details.

Comment: This worked, thank you! I'm not sure how I managed to overlook that in the documentation.

Comment: @Michael Glad it helped you! The documentation is written in such a way that it's easy to overlook and people do.